# nuget command line - how to get version of latest version of package?

Tags: nuget

in a powershell script, i want to be able to know the version of a package on which i depend.  can i get nuget.exe to tell me this information?

i've tried to do something like:

```
nuget list nunit.runners
```

this works fine for some packages, but for some (like the nunit.runners in the example), it returns a whole list of packages instead of just the one i want.

it would suffice if someone could point out a way to make nuget list return only a single item on an exact match on the search condition.

my question is really, though, what is the most straightforward way to ask a nuget feed for the version number of the latest version of a specific package?

Comment: NuGet list, lists the packages that are available from the nuget.org feed. If you would like to see which package version is installed in your project, you can get that info from package.config. curious what's the scenario for which you want this info?

Comment: i want to look at an internal feed and find out what is the latest version of a package that has some shared scripts used by teams in my organization.  i do understand that i am asking for interrogating a feed and not looking at what is installed in my project.  these scripts facilitate common build tasks.  there's not really a project that depends on these, it's more of for build.  other packages are more traditional and reference specific versions and use packages.config and require explict updates, but i want to have scripts that just depend on whatever is the latest from my build server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a [requested feature in codeplex](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2130). I'm working outside of Visual Studio, in PowerShell, and was able to work around using:

```
nuget list id:EntityFramework | ? { $_ -match "^EntityFramework\s+" }
```

Comment: I've created a GitHub issue for this, since CodePlex was shut down: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5138.

Comment: Github ticket was marked closed on Jan 9th, 2024 - the solution being `dotnet package search`.

Answer (score 3):

Just install - **dotnet-search**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-search/

Then run below command:

> dotnet search

This helps for me..!

Comment: Doesn't work with .NET 5 or 6; it's built using .NET Core 2.1.